# Se crea un efecto "raro" al animar nodos usando JavaScript y CSS

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de animar un nodo con JS y CSS, lo que hago es añadir una clase (o eliminarla si ya existe en el elemento) de CSS a un elemento al presionar un botón. La parte de CSS la tengo hecha con *keyframes* y lo que hace es animar a la clase con un `transform`

```js
let animActv = false;

animBtn.addEventListener("click", e => {
  if (animActv) {
    animActv = false;
    animText.classList.remove("bounce-enter");
    setTimeout(() => animText.classList.add("bounce-leave"));
  } else {
    animActv = true;
    animText.classList.remove("bounce-leave");
    setTimeout(() => animText.classList.add("bounce-enter"));
  }
});
```

```css
.bounce-enter {
    animation: bounce-in .5s forwards;
}

.bounce-leave {
    animation: bounce-in .5s reverse;
}

@keyframes bounce-in {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    50% {
        transform: scale(1.5);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(0);
    }
}
```

```html
<p id="animText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc aliquam ex in tellus molestie, commodo rhoncus nulla efficitur.</p>
<button id="animBtn">Animar</button>
```

He comprobado que, si no uso los `setTimeout`, la animación no se reproduce y se ve como si cambiáramos únicamente la propiedad `display`, el problema viene ahora, al usar el `setTimeout` y remover una clase para añadir la otra y que se muestre la animación suave, al volver a mostrar el elemento, se ve el elemento completo por una milésima y después se reproduce la animación, tengo comprendido que esto pasa porque el elemento no tiene ningún tipo de estilo y tampoco puedo editar su propiedad `style` y todo el proceso tengo que hacerlo con JavaScript y CSS.

Lo que deseo lograr sería un efecto suave como el que se logra con VueJS

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#example-2',
  data: {
    show: true
  }
})
```

```css
.bounce-enter-active {
  animation: bounce-in .5s;
}
.bounce-leave-active {
  animation: bounce-in .5s reverse;
}
@keyframes bounce-in {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="example-2">
  <button @click="show = !show">Toggle show</button>
  <transition name="bounce">
    <p v-if="show">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris facilisis enim libero, at lacinia diam fermentum id. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus.</p>
  </transition>
</div>
```

Comment: El problema es que al quitar la clase hay un lapso en el que no hay ninguna clase asignada, entonces sale el texto con scala de 1 por defecto, luego cuando se activa la clase con el reverse pasa de 1 a 0 luego 1.5 y finalmente 1. Ese es el efecto raro.

Comment: @AlfredoMaussa Entiendo que sea eso, el problema es que esto es solo un ejemplo y exporto muchísimas más líneas, es un script que se usará posteriormente en producción y no puede modificar los archivos CSS que haya ahí.

Comment: He probado sin usar CSS directamente, sino con javascript: [element.animate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/animate) y funciona bien.
Está difícil con las clases y el CSS porque apenas quites una clase restaura el tamaño normal antes de que comience la transición y si debería comenzar con scale(0) no lo hará.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo único que necesitas es que la propiedad de escala quede permanente antes de eliminar la clase, de lo contrario, durante una fracción de segundo se mostrará el elemento con la escala original.

Lo más adecuado es hacerlo cuando termine la animación, con el evento `animationend`.

```js
let animActv = false;
// Escuchar cuando termine la animación
animText.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
    // Dejar permanente escala final
    // Y remover clase
    if(animText.classList.contains('bounce-enter')) {
        animText.style.transform = 'scale(0)';
        animText.classList.remove("bounce-enter");
    } else {
        animText.style.transform = 'scale(1)';
        animText.classList.remove("bounce-leave");
    }
});

animBtn.addEventListener("click", e => {
  if (animActv) {
    animActv = false;
    animText.classList.add("bounce-leave");
  } else {
    animActv = true;
    animText.classList.add("bounce-enter");
  }
});
```

```css
.bounce-enter {
    animation: bounce-in .5s forwards;
}

.bounce-leave {
    animation: bounce-in .5s reverse;
}

@keyframes bounce-in {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    50% {
        transform: scale(1.5);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(0);
    }
}
```

```html
<p id="animText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc aliquam ex in tellus molestie, commodo rhoncus nulla efficitur.</p>
<button id="animBtn">Animar</button>
```

De acuerdo a lo que comentas en [tu respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/477320/54039), creo que la opción sugerida por [@AlfredoMaussa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/477276/54039) sería más apropiada, porque cada animación remplaza a la anterior y se mantienen los atributos. Solo necesita un par de adaptaciones, como crear la animación en una variable y aplicar dirección `reverse` cuando sea conveniente:

```js
let animActv = true;
let animFrames = [
    {transform: 'scale(1)', offset: 0},      // offset: 0 = 0% { props }
    {transform: 'scale(1.5)', offset: 0.5},  // offset: 0.5 = 50% { props }
    {transform: 'scale(0)', offset: 1}       // offset: 1 = 100% { props }
];

animBtn.addEventListener("click", e => {
    // Invertir valor de animActv
    animActv = !animActv;
    animText.animate(animFrames, {
        // Establecer dirección de acuerdo a animActv
        direction: (animActv) ? 'reverse' : 'normal',
        fill: 'forwards',    // Conservar propiedades finales de animación
        duration: 500,       // Duración de medio segundo
        iterations: 1        // Ejecutar solo una vez
    });
});
```

```html
<p id="animText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc aliquam ex in tellus molestie, commodo rhoncus nulla efficitur.</p>
<button id="animBtn">Animar</button>
```

Con esto evitas tener que analizar las propiedades que fueron modificadas, así como asignar clase.

Answer (score 2):

##### Observación

El problema es que al quitar la clase hay un lapso en el que no hay ninguna clase asignada, entonces sale el texto con `scale(1)` ya que es el por defecto. Luego, cuando se activa la clase con el 'reverse' pasa de `scale(1)` a `scale(0)` sin transición, luego a `scale(1.5)` y finalmente `scale(1)`. Ese es el efecto raro.

##### Solución

La aproximación que he tomado es con el método `elemento.animate()` ver [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/animate):

La sintáxis es `element.animate(keyframes, options);`  para conservar el último frame se emplea `fill: 'forwards'` en opciones.

```js
let animActv = true;

animBtn.addEventListener("click", e => {
  if (animActv) {
    animActv = false;
animText.animate([
  {transform: 'scale(1)'},
  {transform: 'scale(1.5)'},
  {transform: 'scale(0)'}],
  {fill: 'forwards',duration: 1000,iterations: 1})
  } else {
    animActv = true;
animText.animate([
  {transform: 'scale(0)'},
  {transform: 'scale(1.5)'},
  {transform: 'scale(1)'}],
  {fill: 'forwards',duration: 1000})
  }
});
```

```html
<p id="animText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc aliquam ex in tellus molestie, commodo rhoncus nulla efficitur.</p>
<button id="animBtn">Animar</button>
```

Intenté en el que hace la 'entrada' poner `fill: 'backwards'` como dice en la documentación pero no me funcionó y puse manualmente los 'frames' en reversa.

Answer (score 1):

Las respuestas que actualmente obtengo, son realmente buenas, sin embargo, este es un script que pasará a producción y no se usará solo la propiedad `transform`, como lo aplica @Triby.

Lo que hice para solucionarlo, fue apoyarme de [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle), itero todos los estilos que tiene el elemento y los voy guardando en un objeto, al final del evento `animationended`, vuelvo a usar `getComputedStyle` e itero el objeto que guardó los valores anteriores para ver qué valores cambiaron y guardar en la propiedad `style` los nuevos valores, para devolver la animación, itero el objeto otra vez (el cual fue reasignado y ahora contiene los valores que cambiaron) y voy eliminando los valores de `style`, no elimino directamente la propiedad `style`, porque pueden haber más valores puestos directamente desde el HTML, al final compuebo si `style` no contiene nada, si no contiene nada, ahora sí elimino el atributo.

```js
function Animate(el) {
    const animName = "bounce";
    // El nombre de la animación en @keyframes
    if (el.ANIM_STARTED) {
        // ANIM_STARTED se guarda en el elemento para saber si la animación ha sido iniciada
        el.classList.remove(animName + "-enter");
        // Remover la clase "bounce-enter"
        setTimeout(() => el.classList.add(animName + "-leave"));
        // Añadir la clase "bounce-leave"
        el.ANIM_STARTED = false;
        // Reasignar ANIM_STARTED para que se ejecute normalmente bounce-enter
        const handler = () => {
            // Recorrer el objeto con los estilos
            for (let i in el.stylesSaved) {
                el.style[i] = null;
                // Ir eliminando los estilos
            }
            el.removeEventListener("animationend", handler);
            // Parar el evento
            el.classList.remove(animName + "-leave");
            // Eliminar la clase "bounce-leave"
            if (!el.getAttribute("style")) el.removeAttribute("style");
            // Comprobar si el atributo "sytle" está vacío, si lo está, eliminarlo
            if (!el.getAttribute("class")) el.removeAttribute("class");
            // El atributo "class" también puede quedar vacío, así que hacemos el mismo procedimiento que antes
        }
        // Handler para el evento "animationended"
        el.addEventListener("animationend", handler);
        // Añadir el evento
        return;
        // Parar la ejecución de la función
    }
    // Para bounce-enter
    el.classList.add(animName + "-enter");
    // Añadir la clase "bounce-enter"
    el.classList.remove(animName + "-leave");
    // Eliminar la clase "bounce-leave"
    const css = getComputedStyle(el)
    // Recorrer los estilos del elemento
    el.stylesSaved = {};
    // Guardar el objeto para saber los estilos que cambiaron
    for (let i in css) {
        // Recorrer los estilos
        if (!i.match(/[0-9]/)) {
            // Asegurar que no sea un string numérico, "in" podría iterarnos algunos índices del objeto
            el.stylesSaved[i] = css.getPropertyValue(i);
            // Guardar el estilo en el objeto
        }
    }
    const handler = () => {
        const newStyles = {};
        // El nuevo objeto para saver los estilos que cambiaron
        for (let i in el.stylesSaved) {
            // Iterar los estilos que guardamos antes
            if (!i.match(/[0-9]/)) {
                if (css.getPropertyValue(i) !== el.stylesSaved[i]) {
                    // Comprobar si los estilos cambiaron, es simple: si el estilo anterior es diferente al estilo actual, sabremos que cambió
                    newStyles[i] = getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyValue(i);
                    // Poner el estilo al nuevo objeto
                }
            }
        }
        el.stylesSaved = newStyles;
        // Reasignar stylesSaved para poder iterar en "bounce-leave"
        for (let i in newStyles) {
            // Iterar los nuevos estilos y guardarlos en la propiedad "style" del elemento 
            el.style[i] = newStyles[i];
        }
        el.removeEventListener("animationend", handler);
        // Eliminar el listener
    }
    // El otro handler para el evento
    el.addEventListener("animationend", handler);
    // Eliminar el listener
    el.ANIM_STARTED = true;
    // Reasignar ANIM_STARTED
}

animBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  Animate(animText);
});
```

```css
.bounce-enter {
    animation: bounce-in .5s forwards;
}

.bounce-leave {
    animation: bounce-in .5s reverse;
}

@keyframes bounce-in {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    50% {
        transform: scale(1.5);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(0);
    }
}
```

```html
<p id="animText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc aliquam ex in tellus molestie, commodo rhoncus nulla efficitur.</p>
<button id="animBtn">Animar</button>
```

Comment: Si no tienes inconveniente en llevar la animación a Javascript, revisa la actualización de mi respuesta, basada en la de @AlfredoMaussa para evitar analizar los cambios realizados y simplemente aplicar la nueva animación.

Answer (score 0):

Si entendí bien, lo que hace es que, desaparece y aparece suavemente.
Para eso agregué dos @keyframes; uno para cada efecto: *out* e *in*.

Esto es para desaparecer:

```
.bounce-enter { 
 animation: bounce-out .5s forwards; 
} 
@keyframes bounce-out { 
 0% { 
  transform: scale(1); 
 } 
 50% { 
  transform: scale(1.5); 
 } 
100% { 
  transform: scale(0); 
 } 
}
```

Y esto es para que aparezca (totalmente al revés):

```
.bounce-leave { 
 animation: bounce-in .5s reverse; 
} 
@keyframes bounce-in { 
 100% { 
  transform: scale(0); 
 } 
 50% { 
  transform: scale(1.5); 
 } 
0% { 
  transform: scale(1); 
 } 
}
```

Esto me funcionó a mi y probé en un teléfono.

Comment: Yo aún veo el mísmo efecto 'raro' de la pregunta en esta respuesta. Al menos con el mismo javascript, depronto has probado con un código de javascript distinto para agregar las clases. si es así, por favor, compartelo.

Comment: Bueno, entonces esto si es raro. Estoy usando el mismo JavaScript y CSS más el estilo que respondí y me funciona muy bien.

Comment: Puede que sea la velocidad de renderizado, lo estarás ejecutando en un dispositivo mucho más rápido tal que el frame donde no hay ninguna clase toma menos de 20ms (tiempo para apreciarlo). Si usan el debugger y ejecutan paso a paso se ve claramente que hay un lapso donde no hay ninguna clase por lo tanto está en scale(1) que es el por defecto.